# Clean LUN on HP MSA P2000 G3

Tags: storage-area-network, lun, ovirt

I am trying to deploy a self-host oVirt Engine on a SAN HP MSA P2000 G3 LUN. I created a Vdisk and a volume via the Storage Management Utility (SAN GUI). The volume is already containing data because of previous tests and oVirt documentation specifies that

> LUNs cannot be reused, as is, to create a storage domain or virtual disk. If you try to reuse the LUNs, the Administration Portal displays the following error message: Physical device initialization failed. Please check that the device is empty and accessible by the host.

The solution they give is to use
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/LUN_ID`

Is there a better way to clean LUN via the MSA P2000 GUI or another command line faster than dd (I need to clean 0.5 TB)?

Comment: Can't you just remove the LUN and create a new one?

Comment: I tried but it does not work unfortunatly

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't zero the whole volume. Just a bit in the beginning. Try something like  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/LUN_ID bs=1M count=1

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to `dd` the entire LUN full of zeroes, just a few MB at the beginning. Try `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/LUN bs=1M count=100`